# What happens with sample_weights when implementing custom loss function in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I want to implement my own custom loss function for my (TimeDistributed) AutoEncoder network. Now I'm wondering how my samples_weights will apply to this loss function? Sample_weight is an argument for the model.fit function.

- Will `y_pred`be multiplied by the sample_weight matrix before passing it to the custom_loss_function?
- Or will the returned `loss-tensor` be multiplied by the sample_weight matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The constructor of custom loss take the name of the loss and the reduction algorithm to use to aggregate the individual instance losses. By default, it will be "sum_over_batch_size", which means that the loss will be the sum of instance losses, weighted by the sample weights and divided by the batch size. For detailed information, you can look into the actual code here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/tf-2/keras/engine/training.py